# Consequences of using Structured Exception Handling (SEH)?

Tags: c++, seh, structured-exception

I see Doug Harrison has made a good statement of what is "wrong" with using (i.e. catching) structured exceptions (see [question #3](http://www.360doc.com/content/11/0411/10/6287626_108773107.shtml)).  But what other consequences are there?  For example, what happens if I have several projects compiled with /eha, mixed with other projects compiled with /ehs?  Are there issues when the libraries are linked (compile time or run-time) with eachother?

But that is just one example.  What other issues might there be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/EHa disables an optimization.  With /EHs in effect, the compiler can omit exception filters if it can be sure that no C++ exception is ever thrown by the code wrapped in a try {}.  That's a small space optimization on x86 and x64, very small time optimization on x86.  Problem is, those filters are needed if you catch non-C++ exceptions.  The consequence is that the stack gets unwound when such an exception is caught *without* the destructor of a C++ object getting called.  Not good, /EHa avoids it.

Mixing doesn't cause linker problems.  It causes the above problem.

Yes, /EHa also makes catch(...) do a very stupid thing, it really catches everything.  That ship wreck sailed a while ago though, Pokemon C++ exception handling is a bad idea too.